# How to export an IK structure created in Blender 2.8 to Godot 3.1?

Tags: blender, godot, export, inverse-kinematics

I created this IK bone structure in Blender 2.8 and exported as `.escn`

[image]

As you can see, in Blender it's working ok.
Now, how to use it in Godot?

I've tried export with:

1. `.dae` (native)
2. `.dae` (Better Collada)
3. `.escn`
4. `.glb`

None of them worked...

Is there any tutorial for using imported IK in Godot?

Answer (score -1):

Godot has a [demo project](https://github.com/godotengine/godot-demo-projects) specifically for [inverse-kinematics](https://github.com/godotengine/godot-demo-projects/tree/master/3d/ik). It's not exactly a tutorial but it's a great place to start.

Download the package and use Godot's Project Manager to scan/import the folder for 3d IK.

Comment: As you said, this isn't really an answer to the question. Do you mean that the package is necessary in order to import models from Blender, or that the package has models that are importable?

Comment: This answer would be better if it at least summarized the main strategy described in these links, to preserve that information even if the links were to rot or become inaccessible to certain readers in future.